# Verificar que el usuario ya exista en la base de datos

Tags: php

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
introducir el código aquí
```

// se hace la consulta a la base de datos para optener el nombre del usuario

```
$verificarnombreusu = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT FROM nombreusu WHERE nombreusu = '$nombreusu'");

if ($verificarnombreusu($verificarnombreusu) > 0){
        echo "El usuario existe";
        exit;
    }
```

Comment: y ese código te funciona?, tienes algún error al ejecutarlo?

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! No pongas imagenes a menos que sea absolutamente necesario... Cual es el problema que tenes con este codigo?

Comment: si funciona porque me sigue agregando al usuario pero la variable nombreusu es la que tiene que verificar en la consulta para que no se vuelva a registrar el error que me sale al momento es Uncaught Error: Function name must be a string in

Comment: Prueba haciendo al revés, primero haz la verificación si el usuario existe, y luego el INSERT, Porque, si no me equivoco, primero estás insertando el usuario, y luego verificas si existe o no. Además, de eso, deberías revisar tu base de datos y agregar un UNIQUE a alguna tabla para que no inserte campos repetidos.

Answer (score 1):

segun la definición de https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.query.php, la función  `mysqli_query` te va a devolver tres posibles valores:

- un objeto `mysqli_result`: para casos de SQL de tipo SELECT exitosas
- un valor `TRUE` para otro tipo de SQLS
- valor `FALSE` si hay un error en la consulta

Por lo tanto, si quieres verificar que se ha ejecutado bien la consulta, en tu if debes verificar que el resultado es uno de esos valores. Podrias probar (como suele ser costumbre) con lo siguiente:

```
if ($verificarnombreusu !== false){ // es una consulta select. Es exitosa, deberia ser un objeto tipo mysqli_result
    if($verificarnombreusu->num_rows > 0 ) { // hay mas de un resultado, por lo que existe el nombreusu
        echo "El usuario existe";
        exit;
    } else {
        echo "El usuario no existe";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo soy nuevo en programación PHP, pero veré si puedo serte de ayuda.
Prueba hacer al revés la verificación.

Si mal no lo entiendo, estarías insertando el usuario y luego verificas si existe o no, por lo que recomiendo hacerlo al revés, es decir, primero verificas si existe, y luego lo insertas o no lo insertas.

Te paso el código a ver si funciona:

```
<?php
     include 'cn.php';
     $host = "localhost";
     $username = "root";
     $password = "";
     $db_name = "bdsemar";
     $tbl_name = "usuariosmari";
     $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
     $appater = $_POST['appater'];
     $apmater = $_POST['apmater'];
     $matricula = $_POST['matricula'];
     $servicio = $_POST['servicio'];
     $grado = $_POST['grado'];
     $zona = $_POST['zona'];
     $nombreusu = $_POST['nombreusu'];
     $contra = $_POST['contra'];

     $verificacarnombreusu = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT FROM nombreusu WHERE = '$nombreusu'");
     if ($verificarnombreusu($verificarnombreusu) > 0) {
          echo "El usuario existe";
          exit;
     }else {
          mysqli_query($conexion, "INSERT INTO usuariosmari VALUES('$nombre', $appater', '$apmater', '$matricula', '$servicio', '$grado', '$zona', '$nombreusu, '$contra')");
}

mysqli_close($conexion);
?>
```

Básicamente, lo que hice fue poner la consulta de verificación antes de la inserción de los datos, así primero verificamos y luego, si el usuario existe, no lo insertamos, y si no existe, lo insertamos.

Espero que funcione, o pero lo menos sirva de algo.